# I've just tried "sudo apt-get update" but it failed

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates, sudo

I needed to add some libraries from git but when I tried updating it showed the following error "E: Malformed line 3 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-earth-pro.list (type)
E: The list of sources could not be read."
I don't know if any previous update made any change to that file or what but I cannot use "apt-get" in ubuntu 16.04.

[image]

Comment: No package change will cause the error, a user on your system with `sudo` privileges has added the file and line 3 is incorrect, and needs correction, removal or conversion into a comment.   (`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` is empty unless users with `sudo` rights add files there)

Comment: You (the human) broke apt-get when you made a mistake while installing Google Earth Pro. 1) Look up how to use a Text Editor. 2) Look at Line 3 of that file. 3) Compare Line 3 to what the Google Earth Pro instructions say that it *should* read, and then 4) Fix your typo or mistake using a Text Editor.